# Recently upgraded R - easypackages is broken

Tags: r, package

The title sums it up : I recently upgraded my R to the latest version and from then I get an error trying to load "easypackages".
It basically says that no package named "sessioninfo" is to be found :

[image]

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: That looks like an error in your startup Rprofile code.  Have you tried starting R in "vanilla" mode?  You would use the command line argument "--vanilla".  I'm not certain Windows Rgui supports that, but you can do it using Rterm in a cmd window.

Comment: correct : my Rprofile code calls easypackages ; if I remove it that works... but what I would like is being able to use easypackages

Comment: You probably need to update it and the packages it uses to be compatible with the new R.  After starting in vanilla mode, run `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)` and let it run for a while.  You might need an explicit `install.packages("sessioninfo")` to get that one installed.

Comment: I thought I had already done what you suggested, but apparently no, since what you advised worked. Thank you for your help!